# Making the Angular Material Select Demo Stackblitz into a Standalone Component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, stackblitz

Trying to make the Angular Material Select Demo into a standalone component.

[This is the Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pzhh5o-vnybuo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-form-example.ts)

These are the steps.

Replace `main.ts` with this (For booting standalone component):

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideRouter, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SelectFormExample } from './app/select-form-example';

const routes: Routes = [];

bootstrapApplication(SelectFormExample, {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes)],
});
```

And make the component standalone like this ( Add `standalone` and `imports`.  The imports come from `app.module.ts`):

```
/**
 * @title Select in a form
 */
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialExampleModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  selector: 'select-form-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-form-example.html',
})
```

At this stage it compiles fine, but throws the error:

```
ROR Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
```

The `CommonModule` is already included, and if `BrowserModule` is removed, it creates other problems.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I think you’ll have to do a providersFrom for BrowserModule in you bootStrap providers?

Comment: What other issues have you encountered? It is working for me in this stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/cbdc41?file=src/app/select-form-example.ts

Comment: @Chellappanவ it compiles fine and at first glance looks like it's working, but if you try the top select, you'll notice that the options are not rendered and if you open the developer console, you'll see the errors ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When application bootstrapped using the bootstrapApplication function we need to provide animation module in main.ts

**main.ts**

```
bootstrapApplication(SelectFormExample, {
  providers: [
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient()
  ],
});
```

**[Reference](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/animations/provideAnimations)**

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cbdc41?file=src/main.ts)**

Comment: Awesome - Briliant Insight - Thank you!!!